# Проблема PHP DOMDocument - русские буквы заменяются на мнемоники

Tags: php

Иногда DOMDocument глючит с русскими символами, происходит замена их на непонятные мнемоники.

Происходит это при использовании методов `loadHTML` и `saveHTML`, кодировка файла UTF-8 без BOM, версия PHP 5.4.

Пример:

```
$html = '<p>Текст на русском языке</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
@$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

PHP
Результат:

```
<p>&ETH;&cent;&ETH;&micro;&ETH;&ordm;&Ntilde;&#129;&Ntilde; ...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Исправляет это добавление управляющих байтов UTF-8 (xEFxBBxBF) к началу переменной `$html` и функция `html_entity_decode` на выходе.

```
$html = '<p>Текст на русском языке</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$doc->loadHTML("\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

echo html_entity_decode($doc->saveHTML());

// <p>Текст на русском языке</p>
```